# Unable to find httpd.conf for Tomcat 5.5.27

Tags: tomcat, httpd.conf

I need to configure Tomcat 5.5.27 for disabling weak ciphers, ServerSignature and AuthType but I am unable to find the httpd.conf file. Please let me know about this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat doesn't use httpd.conf, it is not apache.

Instead, take a look at conf folder in tomcat distribution and check online docs for configuring your tomcat version at http://tomcat.apache.org